# Vim colorscheme highlighting issues

Tags: vim

I'm just starting my Vim adventure and am trying to setup https://github.com/haishanh/night-owl.vim as a colorscheme but keep running into weird highlighting issues, certain bits of text have a different background as well as the general background (every line with a ~) I have a feeling that I am missing something completely obvious. This is my .vimrc and im using iTerm2 as terminal:

```
call plug#begin()
    Plug 'haishanh/night-owl.vim'
    Plug 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
    Plug 'pangloss/vim-javascript'
    Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline'
call plug#end()

set expandtab
set shiftwidth=4
set softtabstop=4
set guifont="Fira Code":h40

set termguicolors
set nospell

let g:airline_left_sep = ' ⚡️  '
let $NVIM_TUI_ENABLE_TRUE_COLOR=1

syntax enable
colorscheme night-owl

highlight Normal ctermbg=NONE
highlight NonText ctermbg=NONE
highlight Text ctermbg=NONE
```

[image]

Comment: What's your problem?

Comment: It's a bit hard to see on this screen but `const` `a` `=` etc are all highlighted with a different color. Also all the lines have a different background color below function A()

Comment: What happens if you remove the last three lines (`highlight .... NONE`)  from your vimrc?

Comment: If I remove those lines the colorscheme background is not applied at all. I guess that is the origin of the problem and that those highlight statements shouldnt be necessary in the first place

Comment: You might have more luck asking this question on the vi/vim question site: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score -1):

I fixed this by using MacVim instead of regular Vim!